# how to fetch an image url from image tag that is present within a div tag from flipkart site?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch image url from flipkart site by using beautiful soup and i am getting key value error. I tried fetching the image url from the image class tag present within alt src.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/men/shirts/casual-party-wear-shirts/prsid=2oq,s9b,mg4,vg6&p[]=facets.price_range.from%3DMin&p[]=facets.price_range.to%3D799&otracker=sp_browse_announcement_search.flipkart.com")

html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for img in html('img','_3togXc'):

print(img['alt src'])
```

Expected result is to get image url

```
:src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/309/371/jtsz3bk0/shirt/p/n/r/3xl-twtblshirtful-sh4-tripr-original-imaffycxgppmkknv.jpeg?q=50"
```

... but i am getting key value error.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to show the whole error traceback? It will make finding the problem a lot easier.

Comment: I get _Unfortunately the page you are looking for has been moved or deleted_

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to get in,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html').content)
# Using find gives first occurrence / use select
image_div = soup.find('div',{'class':'figure align-center'}) # Getting complete div element
image_tag = image_div.select('img ') # Getting image element
imageLink = image_tag[0]['src']
imageAlt = image_tag[0]['alt']
#Some Manipulations if required
imageLink = imageLink.replace("../../",'https://matplotlib.org/')
print(imageLink)
print(imageAlt)
```

also please refer some useful selectors here https://sites.google.com/view/way2learnings/programming-languages/python/python-libraries/beautifulsoup